# What does "the folds" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, nouns

This context comes form the video game "Divinity Original Sin II"

> The skeleton reaches into **the folds** of his robes and pulls out a small black mass

What does **the folds** mean? It appeared in the game twice already. The other time it was a letter that was also in the folds of a robe.

**fold**

12. a mark, crease, or **hollow** made by folding (source:Collins English Dictionary)

The definition says "hollow made by folding". Pocket is a hollow so I guess if you folded fabric with which you were making a piece of clothing **you might make a pocket**
but this would require some stitching and not only folding. **Does fold simply mean pocket?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folds of a robe are like the folds of a curtain. Imagine a fabric curtain hanging down. If it's made right, it's not straight. It has a pattern of rounded shapes that form hollow areas.

In fantasy-themed media, characters often wear robes that have lots of these folds because they're mysterious and could be concealing just about anything.

So when a character produces something from "*the folds of their robes*", it means something like, "*from somewhere inside the mysterious shapes of their robes*". We, the audience, are supposed to have no idea if the object was in a pocket, attached by a loop, just suspended there by magic, or if it was pulled through an inter-dimensional portal.

As fantasy readers, we certainly *hope* it wasn't anything as mundane as a pocket!

Comment: Not just in fantasy but in the **real world** millions of people wear loose fitting garments (with numerous names such as caftan, djellaba) with folds, and somewhere in the folds are gaps for pockets etc.